# I want to remove gesture when i click on object of a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

From my side I will try bellow  code, but it is not working.

```
- (void) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
   CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

   NSArray *viewsAtPoint = [self viewsAtPoint:touchPoint];

   for(TheifView * aView in viewsAtPoint)
   {
     [aView removeFromSuperview];
   }
}


- (void) registerGesture
{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please give more specific information beyond "not working".

Answer (score -1):

Gesture target and selector can be removed by following code

```
[gesture removeTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Put tag to ThiefView...say 111. and then u can identify it and remove from self.view. If this is not the answer you expected then explain with clear description..

//For Removing Gestures from View..

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
            if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }
        }
```

//For Removing ThiefView from View

```
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if (subview.tag==111) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove it fully

```
- (void) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
  [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

To remove its target

```
- (void) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
  [gesture removeTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
}
```

To disable the gesture

```
- (void) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
  gesture.enabled=NO;
}
```